# curl in c, output in jq

Tags: c, curl, jq

I make a curl call in c like so:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    CURL *ch;

    CURLcode res;

    ch = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2");

    res = curl_easy_perform(ch);

    curl_easy_cleanup(ch);

    }
```

it prints to the command line just fine:

```
$./mycurl
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 2,
  "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
  "completed": false
}
```

but I would like to use jq to parse the json and output from one compiled c file. how do i do this without doing: `./mycurl | jq`

but rather compile it all in one?

Comment: You can run `jq` from your C code, pass it the JSON on stdin, and read the response on stdout. Things to look up include `pipe`, `fork`, `popen`, etc. There are lots of examples on this site and elsewhere showing how to interact with programs like this.

Comment: thank you for the response. i will look those up. sometimes you just need the word to look for.

Comment: *but I would like to use jq to parse the json* Why would you want to do that?  Just use a JSON-parsing library directly in your C code, such as [JSON-C](https://github.com/json-c/json-c)

Comment: The "unix way" is to have small utilities that do one thing (well), that you can connect together. Trying to reproduce that in C code seems pointless. What are you actually trying to achieve, that requires this to be part of a C program, rather than, for example, a shell script?

Comment: thanks @AndrewHenle. will look. sounds like exactly what i want.

Comment: @pmacfarlane just for kicks.

Comment: Wikipedia has a decent explanation of the ["unix way"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy). For sure make your program for fun, but then think if that is the best way.

Comment: @pmacfarlane absolutely. i agree. just learning the ropes of c so i'm replicating some simple stuff i've written in bash and php as a kind of self tutorial. i will read the link you provided. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted it's a much better idea to use a JSON library to parse the output.  A library provides you with an API which is a more direct way to express what you are trying to do, and will provide you with better error handling.  That said, I was curious, so here is how you could pass the data to `jq`:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 2
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = popen("jq .userId", "w");
    if(!f) {
        printf("jq failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    dup2(fileno(f), STDOUT_FILENO);
    CURL *ch = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2");
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(ch);
    curl_easy_cleanup(ch);
    fclose(stdout);
    return pclose(f);
}
```

and output:

```
1
```

Comment: thank you for the time spent. its not wasted. your code works. i will play with this for edutainment.